# Optaplanner null pointer exception in during solving - cross referenced objects and ReflectionPropertyAccessor class

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception, setter, optaplanner

I have 2 classes - `Dev` and `Task`. `Tasks` get assigned to `Dev`s in the planning stage. One of my planning variables `assignedDev` has a setter as below:

```
public void setAssignedDev(Dev dev){
    this.assignedDev=dev;       
    dev.addToTasksAssigned(this); //null pointer exception here
            }
```

I need to keep a log of the `task`s that have been assigned to each dev in the `Dev` class, so it is necessary for me to refer this task across.

When I run the solver, I get the following error message:

```
31:53.968 [main] INFO  o.o.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver - Solving started: time spend (222), score (null), new best score (-36000hard/0soft), random seed (0).
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The property (assignedDev) setter on bean of class (class taskassignment.domain.Task) throws an exception.
at         org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.ReflectionPropertyAccessor.executeSetter(ReflectionPropertyAccessor.java:80)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.PlanningVariableDescriptor.setValue(PlanningVariableDescriptor.java:308)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMove.doMove(ChangeMove.java:66)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.ConstructionHeuristicDecider.doMove(ConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:101)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.ConstructionHeuristicDecider.decideNextStep(ConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:73)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicSolverPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicSolverPhase.java:67)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.runSolverPhases(DefaultSolver.java:190)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:155)
at taskassignment.app.TaskAssignmentHelloWorld.main(TaskAssignmentHelloWorld.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at taskassignment.domain.Task.setAssignedDev(Task.java:119)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.ReflectionPropertyAccessor.executeSetter(ReflectionPropertyAccessor.java:75)
... 8 more
```

This error is coming from this clause in the ReflectionPropertyAccessor class (in the Optaplanner software), when it invokes the bean `Object`:

```
public void executeSetter(Object bean, Object value) {
    try {
        writeMethod.invoke(bean, value);
    } catch  //..... blah blah
```

How is this class managing to provide an instance of the `Task` class, yet still generate a null exception? The `task` is clearly not null (I even checked using an `if(this!=null)` clause), so how can it be passing on a null value?

Is there a workaround for this?

Let me know if I've been unclear. Many thanks

Comment: You talk a lot about `Task` not pointing to null, but to me it looks like `dev == null` here: `dev.addToTasksAssigned(this); //null pointer exception here`

Comment: But in that case, why would it not throw the null pointer exception 2 lines above?

Comment: What do you mean with 2 lines above? Isn't `dev.addToTasksAssigned(this);` line `Task.java:119` ?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you start with an uninitialized Solution and let the Construction Heuristics initialize it. In an uninitialized Solution, all `Task` instances start with a `assignedDev` property set to  `null`. During CH, the Solver will regularly set that `assignedDev` property to a non-null `Dev` instance, and then undo that change by setting it back to `null`. (The reason for undo-ing relates to incremental score calculation for scalability & performance.)

So during the undo, it calls `writeMethod.invoke(someTask, null);`, which calls `someTask.setAssignedDev(null)`, which NPE's on `null.addToTasksAssigned(someTask);`. Logical.